# validate if artifact got published to nexus successfully

Tags: gradle, nexus

My requirement is to publish snapshot artifact to nexus snapshot repository and validate if the artifact go published successfully.
Approaches I am considering are,

1. Verify if the timestamp(`<last-modified>` field in rest response) of the published artifact is later then build start time.
2. Compare if the last latest artifact has different SHA1 hashing then after I have published the artifact.
3. Fetch the timestamp from within maven-metadata.xml and make a rest request to artifact with timestamp and see if it exists.

With respect to approach #1 I am not able to see any rest-api that returns me the timestamp for the published artifact, So i am trying to fetch the entire response for an artifact for a snapshot version and I am parsing the XML and finding the latest published artifact and its date. Just to validate of its authenticity. For this approach, as we are considering Snapshots here, the returned response will have info for them all for a specific version and which may grow large based on development efforts.

So I am interested if there is neat way to fetch nexus timestamp/last-modified for any given artifact and version?

Side note: None of the above approaches are convincing to me. I could not even get much details on best way to verify if the artifact got published successfully.

Is there any smarter and robust way of doing it?

- Nexus: 2.12.0-01
- Gradle: 4.6
- Jenkins: 2.26

Answer (score 0):

We are using artifactory, an equivalent technology to nexus repository manager, and we use the `REST` api to get the `sha256` of artifacts that we have deployed.

I am sure there is a similar `REST` api to Nexus that enables you to get the metadata (including sha's) of an artifact.

Since you are dealing with snapshot builds, it's important that you get the `sha256` and not just the timestamp. Reason being, if someone else deploys the same artifact simultaneously, you dont know which one was deployed.

Here's a reference to the assets api that might be helpful.

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api

As a last comment I would suggest switching to non-snapshot builds. If you deploy snapshot builds to a repository, those builds can be overwritten at any time by anybody, and you are opening up for a whole set of challenges if you use snapshot builds.